# Validate xml on Mono

Tags: xml, validation, mono

I have a .net application which I want to port to Mono.
The application takes a xml file validates it and "executes" the xml.

The validation part is not working on Mono. The xml is validating against XSD.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler(XmlValidationEventHandler);

settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.Schemas.Add("http://eltrade.com/" + m_Schema, XmlReader.Create(stream));
stream.Close();

Console.WriteLine("Create xmlValidationReader");

// Validate the XML with XS
using (XmlReader xmlValidationReader = XmlReader.Create(m_document, settings))
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin xml validation");

        while (xmlValidationReader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xmlValidationReader.ReadInnerXml());
            Console.WriteLine("---");
        }
    }
    catch (XmlSchemaException SE)
    {
        m_success = false;
        Console.WriteLine("XmlSchemaException: " + SE.Message + " " + SE.SourceSchemaObject.SourceUri);
    }
    catch (XmlException XE)
    {
        m_success = false;
        Console.WriteLine("XMLException: " + XE.Message + " " + XE.SourceUri);
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        m_success = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + E.Message);
    }
}
```

When I run the validation (the above function), only the first line of the xml is read and exception is thrown: Cannot cast source type to destination type. Unable to cast object of type 'System.UInt32' to type 'System.Int64'.

```
<bons xmlns="http://eltrade.com/schema-file-driver.xsd">
  <receipt id="10">
    <type>
      <nonfiscal/>
    </type>
    <prints>
      <line>
        <text>Free text at the top of receipt.</text>
        <wordwrap>true</wordwrap>
      </line>
      <payments>
        <pay1>all</pay1>
      </payments>
    </prints>
  </receipt>
</bons>
```

On windows with the .Net framework everything is working fine.
With Mono (on Linux and Windows) the validation throws the above exception.

**Using Mono v.2.4.2.3 on the Linux (kubuntu) machine and

Mono v.2.6.4 on the Windows machine.**

What would be the cause of the exception?

```
<bons xmlns="http://eltrade.com/schema-file-driver.xsd">
```

doesn't contains any numeric value to cast it to Int64.